# Creating queue from two stacks

Tags: java, stack, queue

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here ?
I am trying to create a queue from two stacks as per a book exercise. I get error "Stack Underflow" from the peek function. But everything seems right to me :P Please explain. Thanks!

```
//Program to implement Queue using two Stacks.

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Ex3_5_Stack {
    int N;
    int countOfNodes=0;
    private Node first;

    class Node {
        private int item;
        private Node next;
    }

    public Ex3_5_Stack() {
        first=null;
        N=0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first==null;
    }

    public void push(int item){
        if (this.countOfNodes>=3) {
            Ex3_5_Stack stack = new Ex3_5_Stack();
            stack.first.item=item;
            N++;
        } else {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = new Node();
            first.item=item;
            first.next=oldfirst;
            N++;
        }
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack Underflow");

        int item = first.item;
        first=first.next;
        return item;
    }

    public int peek() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack Underflow");

        return first.item;
    }
}
```

And MyQueue file

```
public class Ex3_5_MyQueue {
    Ex3_5_Stack StackNewest,StackOldest;

    public Ex3_5_MyQueue() {
        super();
        StackNewest = new Ex3_5_Stack();
        StackOldest = new Ex3_5_Stack();
    }

    public int size() {
        return StackNewest.size()+StackOldest.size();
    }

    public void add(int value) {
        StackNewest.push(value);
    }

    private void transferStack() {
        if (StackOldest.isEmpty()) {
            while (StackNewest.isEmpty()) {
                StackOldest.push(StackNewest.pop());
            }
        }
    }

    public int peek() {
        this.transferStack();
        return StackOldest.peek();
    }

    public int remove() {
        this.transferStack();
        return StackOldest.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ex3_5_MyQueue myQueue = new Ex3_5_MyQueue();
        myQueue.add(4);
        myQueue.add(3);
        myQueue.add(5);
        myQueue.add(1);
        System.out.println(myQueue.peek());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `transferStack()`, you're missing an exclamation mark. It should be:

```
private void transferStack(){
    if(StackOldest.isEmpty()){
        while(!StackNewest.isEmpty()){ // you forgot it here
            StackOldest.push(StackNewest.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, why do you have that `if (this.countOfNodes>=3)` clause in your stack `push()` code? You're creating a brand new stack, shoving the item in there, and then you don't even save that new stack, so all you have is your old items, even though your count went up by 1.

Comment: Thanks! well that is for another related program. No relevance to above mentioned objective.

Comment: If you say so, though I hope whatever it is for is well documented so that it's known why it does that.